# Resolution of the dependency failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have the following code:

**CancellationPolicyService**

```
using MyApp.Model.Models;
using Repository.Pattern.Repositories;
using Service.Pattern;

namespace MyApp.Service
{
    public interface ICancellationPolicyService :  IService<CancellationPolicy>
    {
    }

    public class CancellationPolicyService : Service<CancellationPolicy>, ICancellationPolicyService
    {
        public CancellationPolicyService(IRepositoryAsync<CancellationPolicy> repository)
        : base(repository)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Inside **UnityConfig.cs**:

```
.RegisterType<ICancellationPolicyService, CancellationPolicyService>()
```

In DataCacheService:

```
namespace MyApp.Service
{
    public class DataCacheService
    {
    private ICancellationPolicyService CancellationPolicyService
        {
            get { return _container.Resolve<ICancellationPolicyService>(); }
        }

        public DataCacheService(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;

            MainCache = new MemoryCache("MainCache");

            GetCachedItem(CacheKeys.CancellationPolicies);
        }
    public object GetCachedItem(CacheKeys CacheKeyName)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!MainCache.Contains(CacheKeyName.ToString()))
                {
                    switch (CacheKeyName)
                    {
                        case CacheKeys.CancellationPolicies:
                            var cancellationpolicies = CancellationPolicyService.Queryable().ToList();
                            UpdateCache(CacheKeys.CancellationPolicies, cancellationpolicies);
                            break;
                        }
                };
                return MainCache[CacheKeyName.ToString()] as Object;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I call DataCacheService I get an error saying the following:

```
InvalidOperationException - The current type, Repository.Pattern.Repositories.IRepositoryAsync`1[MyApp.Model.Models.CancellationPolicy], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

Do you have an idea, why that is? I would be thankful for any kind of hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't registered `IRepositoryAsync<CancellationPolicy>`. Add that registration to your unity registration as well.

Assuming that the implementation of `IRepositoryAsync<CancellationPolicy>` is `CancellationPolicyRepository`:

```
.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<CancellationPolicy>, CancellationPolicyRepository>()
```

Or someting like this if you have a generic repository.

```
.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<CancellationPolicy>, MyGenericRepository<CancellationPolicyRepository>>()
```

Answer (score 1):

use this one:

```
RegisterType<yourInterface>().As<yourClass>().AsSelf();
```

it might work.

Comment: did it work? if yes then mark it as answer. So others will know.

Comment: Thank you. I added .RegisterType <ICancellationPolicyService>().As<CancellationPolicyService>().AsSelf() to UnityConfig, but .As is not a valid method. What would I have to change?

Comment: Are you using Autofac for your dependency Injection?

Comment: if yes then It has to work. you might want to add AutoFac Integration MVC too. check for autofac MVC5 in nuget packages online. you will find it.

Comment: No, I am not using AutoFac. Is there a way to do it without. I registered other types successfully. I dont know, why this one is not working.